# Do I need external IPs for Managed Instance Group instances serving as a GLB back-end?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

(Related to [Why do I need an external address to make an internal connection between GCE instances?](https://serverfault.com/questions/940061/why-do-i-need-an-external-address-to-make-an-internal-connection-between-gce-ins))

I have a MIG that serves as a GLB back-end. The health-checks for both the MIG and the GLB back-ends fail if I don't assign external IPs to the instances.

Does the GLB just rewrite the packets on the way in to point to the instance external IPs?

VPC, firewalls, and routes are the same as in the linked question above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to Google Cloud Support, yes you need external IP addresses. The Health Check systems use instances' external IPs to connect. Proper firewall configuration is required per https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#firewall_rules.

Regarding the rewriting of packets, no. GLB is a non-proxying "pass-through" load-balancer per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205917/what-is-pass-through-load-balancer-how-is-it-different-from-proxy-load-balancer and https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/.

Comment: This is incorrect, VM instances used as backends do not require external IPs to receive traffic from HTTP(S) and TCP proxy load balancers. External IPs are, however, required if you are using a standard network load balancer (no proxy) as these do not use backend services.

Comment: Google Cloud support says otherwise for Managed Instance Groups (MIGs) as back-ends, but I've had issues with their claims before. Do you have a link to documentation that supports your claim?

Comment: Nothing explicit, no. It's the lack of documentation that supports it. If external IPs were a necessity, it would be included in one of the many restrictions listed (such as found [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#restrictions_and_guidance) )

Comment: to be honest, if someone at cloud support told you it is necessary, I believe they were wrong. I would suggest reaching back out to them for clarification, or, if they insist it is necessary, ask for explicit documentation to support the fact (it does not exist)

Comment: Given that health checks are required for GLB back-ends (ie you cannot create a GLB MIG back-end without a health check), and given the documentation link above that states that health checks must have external IPs as targets, I disagree with your claim that *no* documentation exists, and that my response (and that of Google Support) is incorrect. I'm happy to correct/remove my response if you can show sufficient proof to the contrary.

Comment: GKE private clusters use no external IPs for the VMs (MIG) and use GCLB with Health Checks for ingress and work without issue. You should be able to reliably create an HTTP(S) load balancer with health checks while targetting a managed instance group without external IPs. I can't find docs, but I have no issue creating this setup and exposing it to the internet. Just make sure you have firewall rules that whitelist the LB IP ranges as per the docs

Answer (score 1):

You do not need external IP for your instances serving as the backend for GCP Load Balancer. When a user request comes in, the load balancing service distributes the request to a backend services and instances from it. The backend instance does not need an external IP for this to work. Please see these  links [1] [2] more information about GCP Load Balancing and Backend Services.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/

[2]https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for external instance IPs being part of a MIG. Just make sure you have an appropriate firewall rule in place to let the health check pass through (130.211.0.0/22, 35.191.0.0/16). Have a look at the [multiple-certs](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-lb-http/tree/master/examples/multiple-certs) example in `terraform-google-lb-http`.